# How to enforce an array on "@type" in jsonld?

Tags: json-ld

Given a context with an aliased `type` like this:

```
{
  "@context" : {
      "type" : "@type"
  }
}
```

How can an array be enforced onto the data like with using

```
"@container" : "@set"
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JSON-LD 1.0 this can't be achieved, as @type has its definition fixed by the specification. You can create aliases (such as type) but you can't change the behavior.

In the forthcoming JSON-LD 1.1, this has issue has been solved, and you can do exactly as proposed -- add @container: @set to the definition, and the compaction algorithm will add the types to an array.

The relevant issue in the 1.1 working group: https://github.com/w3c/json-ld-syntax/issues/34

Comment: I recently implemented this spec for the java library https://github.com/jsonld-java/jsonld-java#2018-11-03.